# Reusing a function returning a inner function

Tags: javascript, closures

How can I make f ("Michael") return a string "Michael"?

I need f() to yield "Michael" and f ("Michael")("Jackson") to yield Michael Jackson

```js
    function f (firstName) {
        var nameIntro = "This celebrity is ";
        
       function lastName (theLastName) {
            return nameIntro + firstName + " " + theLastName;
        }
        return lastName;
    }
    
    
    
    console.log(f ("Michael")("Jackson"))

I'm really after a solution for this..
The above original question was not precise enough..
f()='f'
f('it' ) == 'fit'
f()('x') == 'fox'
f()()('bar') == 'foobar'
```

Comment: please format the code :)

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'm really after a solution that will make it reusable. I mean as follows..f()()()()()(s)== 'fooooo' + s;
f('it' ) == 'fit'
f()('x') == 'fox'
f()()('bar') == 'foobar' The main problem is f() (on it's own) returns a string but f()('x') will return 'fox' so (i suppose) f() will conditionally return a string or a closure. But what is the optimum solution? Closure expert needed..

Answer (score 2):

You could implement a [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) function, which called, if the environment expects a primitive value.

```js
function f(firstName) {
    function lastName(theLastName) {
        return nameIntro + firstName + " " + theLastName;
    }
    var nameIntro = "This celebrity is ";

    lastName.toString = function () { return firstName; };
    return lastName;
}
    
console.log(f("Michael")("Jackson"));
console.log(f("Michael"));
```

Comment: This doesn't work using JSFiddle in Firefox. It returns `function lastName()` as one of those object drop downs.

Comment: @ChaosPandion, it looks, that your environment does not expect a string. if you use the reuslt for creating a string, you get a string instead of the function.

Comment: It's a very clever solution, but quite something to read. "when printing last name, print first name", "the last name function returns an intro and a first name before the last name".  I think the confusion comes from the odd goal in the OP.  (Also, I'm confused as to the origin of the leading whitespace when called with just "Michael")

Comment: @danh, the space looks more like a bug of the implementation of `console.log`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take with an explicit property added to the returned function.

```
function nameFormatter(firstName) {
    var intro = "This celebrity is ";

  function rest (lastName) {
    return intro + firstName + " " + lastName;
  }

  rest.firstName = firstName;
  return rest;
}

var f = nameFormatter("Michael")
console.log(f);
console.log(f.firstName);
console.log(f("Jackson"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but I'm really after something that will do this.. nameFormatter()()()()()(s)== 'fooooo' + s;
nameFormatter('it' ) == 'fit'
nameFormatter()('x') == 'fox'
nameFormatter()()('bar') == 'foobar'